# Why is Google showing "AP election results" but the AP is not?

Tags: united-states, election

If I Google "election results" right now (7:24PM EST Nov 3 2020) then a box shows up provided by google with state summaries of precincts reporting according to the AP. But if I click on the provided link to the AP I do not see any election results. Also, if I go to the [AP's Election 2020 web sit](https://apnews.com/hub/election-2020)e, once again there are no election results, just editorial "stories".

So, I don't get this. Google is reporting the AP's data, but the AP is not publishing their own data, except through Google. Huh?

Answer (score 2):

The AP is publishing their calls at https://apnews.com/article/ap-explains-race-calls-0b1988605f9101f4b799fc63b01e0090